# Маршрутизация двух сетевых карт

Tags: подсети, сеть

Имеется две сетевые карты (А и Б). Нужно настроить маршрутизацию таким образом, чтобы сидеть в интернете с карты А, а для работы только в Б. (работать должны одновременно).Советовали воспользоваться командой

```
ROUTE -p ADD ip_address_or_network MASK mask_value gateway
```

Но то ли у меня руки кривые, то ли растут не с того места, но что то у меня не получается.Сообщаю кое какие данные:То что прописано у меня на компе:

```
 IP первой: 192.168.0.2 Маска: 255.255.255.0 Шлюз: 192.168.0.1 IP второй: 192.168.1.2 Маска: 255.255.255.0 Шлюз: 192.168.1.1.
```

Настройки на модеме:

```
ip - адрес 10.23.98.49255.255.255.252шлюз 10.23.98.50
```

Роутинг на модеме

```
Select  State   Destination Subnet Mask NextHop Metric  Itf    Enable  10.0.0.0    255.0.0.0   10.23.98.50 20  a0
```

Вот. Как же тогда прописать команду правильно? Сколько раз не пытался - не помогло. Желательно написать подробно. (((((((

Answer (score 1):

Модем и комп - в одной подсети, предположим, это `192.168.0.0`. Соответственно надо прописать  `Dest:0.0.0.0 GW:192.168.0.1` с приоритетом 2.

Для второй карты на внутреннюю локаль:

```
Dest:192.168.1.0 MASK:255.255.255.0 GW:192.168.1.1 с приоритетом 1
```

должно заработать.

Comment: Это рассматриваете что один модем. Но модема на самом деле 2 и один идет на интернет (оптика), другой (дсл) для работы

Comment: На ХэшКоде Вам же ответили: прописать для т.н. "рабочей" карты необходимые маршруты - допустим для работы необходим доступ к 10 известным Вам адресам (подсетям), вот их и пропишите. Обязательно маршрут по умолчанию должен вести через карту, называемую Вами "интернет". Поймите: Вам описывают логику построения, применять и корректировать данные Вам примеры Вы должны сами.

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что модем A имеет некоторые настройки и будет использоваться для доступа в интернет, а на компьютере прописано следующее:

```
IP первой: 192.168.0.2 Маска: 255.255.255.0 Шлюз: 192.168.0.1
```

Второй же модем, Б, используется для работы, тогда для него не нужно прописывать Шлюз:

```
IP второй: 192.168.1.2 Маска: 255.255.255.0 Шлюз: оставить пустым
```

Затем, предположим, что работа у вас ведется на сервере (10.24.0.1) и в сети (10.25.0.0/24) тогда вам необходимо два правила в таблице маршрутизации:

```
route -p add 10.24.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.2route -p add 10.25.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2
```

Таким образом вы обеспечите выход туда, куда нужно через модем Б, все остальное заберет на себя модем А.

Comment: смысл прописывать адрес к ресурсу, если уже прописан адрес к его подсети? Масло масляное...

Comment: Где вы увидали ресурс принадлежащий сети?

Comment: да, действительно, извиняюсь - проглядел... Однако мне кажется, что без указания шлюза вторая карта работать не будет (хотя могу и ошибаться)...

Comment: @Justicet, этого достаточно для базовой работы устройства. Сеть ведь может использоваться и без маршрутизатора.

Answer (score 0):

внутренний IP-адрес модема забыл указать. Его нужно указывать шлюзом в маршруте. А что означает "для работы"? Тоже интернет, только для работы? Или это не интернет? Просто компьютер же не знает, где работа, а где что.

Comment: А более подробно можно?

Comment: У модема какой адрес в сети 192.168.x.x?У тебя получается, что ты на десятку пытаешься ходить через десятку. Шлюзом может быть тот адрес, который находится в твоей же подсети. У тебя эта подсеть 192.168.0.0/24 или 192.168.1.0/24